# Autofac: opening manually lifetime scope

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, autofac

we all know that working with Autofac under MVC is so easy having set dependency resolver but latelly we are about to use DI/IoC in console app where things are not so simple.

Code first:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

// sample registrations not important
builder.RegisterType<MessageCommandHandler>().Named<IHandler<Message>>("handler");

builder.RegisterDecorator<IHandler<Message>>(
    (c, inner) => new TransactionalHandlerDecorator<Message>(inner), 
    fromKey: "handler", 
    toKey: "transactional");

var container = builder.Build();

using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
    var scopedHandler = scope.Resolve<IHandler<Message>>();
    scopedHandler.Handle(new Message());
}
```

as u see i'm manually creating lifetime scope but i wonder what is the correct way of woking with scopes in for example console app? Should I use it in that way:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

// sample registrations not important
builder.RegisterType<MessageCommandHandler>().Named<IHandler<Message>>("handler");

builder.RegisterDecorator<IHandler<Message>>(
    (c, inner) => new TransactionalHandlerDecorator<Message>(inner), 
    fromKey: "handler", 
    toKey: "transactional");

var container = builder.Build();

var handler = container.Resolve<IHandler<Message>>();
handler.Handle(new Message());
```

What would be difference? Which one is suggested way of using lifetime scopes in console app?

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/index.html) on controlling scope and lifetime? After reading that documentation, do you still have the same question?

Comment: This link is better: https://nblumhardt.com/2011/01/an-autofac-lifetime-primer/ . Mainly builder.Build() returns IContainer which is root life time scope but as suggested it is good practice when u setting clear boundaries of lifetimescope using var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope(). Personally i don;t like approch when i have to inject ILifetimeScope to services to create nested scopes.